# Character comparison at starting and ending of each string in a csv file uploading

Tags: php

I have .csv file, in that strings are looking like

```
"9.30 AM"
"Username"
"Message"
""
"9.30 AM"
"Username"
"Message"
""
```

Here I want to separate these and need to store in database withe separate columns. Means time will come to time column , username will its own column like. When "" comes need to check next line

means

```
"9.30 AM"
"Username"
"Message"
```

How do I do this?

I tried

```
echo startsWith($str, '|'); //Returns true
echo endsWith($str, '}'); //Returns true
```

Comment: What are those functions, `startsWith` and `endsWith` ? and how can both return true since you don't have such characters `'|'` nor `'}'` ?

Comment: did you try `startNextComumn` and `sendFieldToUsername` ??? show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to return it as an array.
Then use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split it in to separate messages and loop it.

I added an array_map to remove the `"` around the values, but if it's not needed just use the commented line.

```
//$csv = file("filename.csv");
$csv = ['"9.30 AM"',
'"Username"',
'"Message"',
'""',
'"9.30 AM"',
'"Username"',
'"Message"',
'""'];

$messages = array_chunk($csv, 4);

foreach($messages as $mess){
    list($time, $user, $m) = array_map(function ($a) { return trim($a, '"'); }, $mess);
    //list($time, $user, $m) = $mess;
    echo $time . " " . $user . " " . $m . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Insider the foreach loop you can use the variables to whatever you need.
https://3v4l.org/alctq